# Expanding phrases not merely words in abbrev-mode

Tags: abbrev

Emacs `abbrev-mode` is very helpful for expanding words into other words or phrases. For example, I can ask Emacs to expand "`edv`" into "`Emacs Developmental Version`". However, it seems only to be able expand words, not phrases. For example, it does not appear to be able to expand "`Emacs Developmental Version`" into "`edv`". This problem arises when one is editing texts one had not typed up oneself, as I am doing with a project I am working on. Just to note that in Sublime Text, one can expand phrases into words and other phrases, using the snippet feature. The same limitation in Emacs pertains to `yasnippet`.

Comment: So why don't you use Sublime Text for this application? Once you've done the transformation you want, you can go back to Emacs. Emacs is a great set of tools but it does not cover everything. BTW, I would have used `sed` for the example you show above.

Comment: Excellent advice. Thanks @NickD.

Comment: Why don't your query-replace "Emacs Developmental Version" to "edv"? Or I don't understand the problem. Surely, you don't to type "Emacs Developmental Version" just to  get "edv" as an expansion.

Comment: As I said, Tom, I am editing pre-existing text. The nature of the revisions are such that query-replace cannot work for me. I need an on hand tool like abbrev where I can expand words and phrases as I read through the text if I feel a change is warranted.